# Is it possible to include AngularJs to a project with Gradle

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, gradle

I know that it is possible to include AngularJs with Maven into a Spring project for instance but how would one include it with Gradle?

Looking into gradle repository I find no AngularJs entries. Maybe it's possible to fetch it from Maven repository with Gradle? But how would one do that.

Comment: I suggest you work through [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) getting started exercise.

Comment: The exercise you suggested include angular by fetching it from google with HTML script tag. I would like Gradle to automatically get me the angular files into my project folder.

Comment: See the script tag? Add a script to fetch that URL. Maven and Gradle are for Java; not JavaScript. Potentially, you could use bower and npm but I struggle to understand why you need to automate this step (or why you'd want to serve it yourself instead of using the Google CDN).

Comment: Because HTML loads all the included assets first, and when that is done it will load the rest of the HTML. Fetching assets from web will slow page load.

Comment: Except that everyone who loads (and caches) that file from Google already has it in their cache; with your method they have `n` copies of it in the cache (where `n` is the number of angularjs sites they visit).

Comment: Allright, will go with that solution then. Thanks!

Comment: Also, when Google fixes bug(s) you get the benefit without having to recompile and redeploy your site. If it's an absolute requirement that you serve the files yourself (e.g. business overrules you) then I'd start looking at bower and npm.

Comment: In an enterprise production environment you do not want your browser to contact a CDN all the time. You also want to control the exact version of angular you are using. So actually there is a very good reason to do this using Gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it turned out in the discussion below the question that it doesn't make sense to download angular via gradle it can be done with the following piece of code:

```
repositories {
   ivy {
      name = 'AngularJS'
      url = 'https://code.angularjs.org/'
      layout 'pattern', {
         artifact '[revision]/[module](.[classifier]).[ext]'
      }
   }
}

configurations {
   angular
}

dependencies {
   angular group: 'angular', name: 'angular', version: '1.3.9', classifier: 'min', ext: 'js'
}

task fetch(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.angular
   into 'src/main/webapp/js'
   rename {
      'angular.js'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I have **AngularJS 2** + **Spring Boot** application with **Gradle**. I use *typescript* (.ts file) and *npm* (node js package manager). So I'm running *npm install* for generate node_modules and *npm run tsc* for translating typescript to javascript. I still use some of webjars though, basically dependencies are gathered by npm task during build time and wired by systemjs.config.js file

Below is my folder structure

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources
                   /app           - .ts files and .js translated from .ts
                   /css
                   /js            - systemjs.config.js
                   /node_modules  - generated by npm install
                   /typings       - generated by npm install
                   package.json
                   tsconfig.json
                   typings.json
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp      - .jsp files
```

This is my build.gradle file and add two custom tasks (npmInstall and npmRunTsc) to run npm tasks

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'my-angular-app'
    version =  '1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.my.Application'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

task npmInstall(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'src/main/resources'
    commandLine 'npm', 'install'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}

task npmRunTsc(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'src/main/resources'
    commandLine 'npm', 'run', 'tsc'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:1.0.3.RELEASE",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:1.0.3.RELEASE",
            "com.google.code.gson:gson",
            "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6",
            "commons-collections:commons-collections",
            "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10",
            "commons-io:commons-io:2.4",
            "com.h2database:h2",
            "org.hibernate:hibernate-core",
            "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager",
            "org.webjars:datatables:1.10.5",
            "org.webjars:datatables-plugins:ca6ec50",
            "javax.servlet:jstl",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper",
            "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1",
            "org.jolokia:jolokia-core",
            "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver",
            "org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16",
            "commons-jexl:commons-jexl:1.1",
            "cglib:cglib:3.2.1",
            "org.flywaydb:flyway-core",
            )
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile("junit:junit",
                "org.springframework:spring-test",
                "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test",
                "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2",
                "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2",
                )
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

When I run the gradle build process I run like below

```
$ gradle clean npmInstall npmRunTsc test bootRepackage
```

I can use same systemjs.config.js shown on AngularJS tutorial

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];
  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And on .jsp file I include the systemjs.config.js in head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

For last, to sort out context path I do like below on my Spring WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/images/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/images/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/css/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/js/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/app/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/app/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/node_modules/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/node_modules/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/node_modules/");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad at all. I will try that out!

Answer (score 7):

Check out [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/), i highly recommend it.

I've just used it in Maven and Gradle project.
Basically it is just what we needed, a vast collection of front-end projects and frameworks packaged in jars.

- Add this dependency to your `build.gradle` script:

  `compile 'org.webjars:angularjs:1.3.14'`
- Go to documentation section for a quick setup guide for Spring
- include `angular.js` or some other module from the jar in you script like a local resource

  `<script src="where-you-exposed-webjars/angular/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>`
- Or optionaly require it from `require.js` script

Answer (score 3):

It may be late, but checkout https://github.com/gharia/spring-boot-angular.
This is Spring Boot project with angular JS using asset-pipeline.

EDIT:

Using [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/craigburke/client-dependencies-gradle), we can easily manage the client side dependencies, either of npm or bower or GIT. Please see the sample build.gradle below, in which I have included several dependencies of Angular in `clientDependencies`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.6")
        classpath("gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client:flyway-release:4.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.craigburke.client-dependencies' version '1.0.0-RC2'
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

jar {
    baseName = 'boot-demo'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

clientDependencies {


    npm {
        'angular'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular.js'
            include 'angular.min.js'
        }
        'angular-resource'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-resource.js'
            include 'angular-resource.min.js'
        }
        'angular-mocks'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-mocks.js'
            include 'angular-mocks.min.js'
        }
        'angular-route'('1.5.x', into: 'angular'){
            include 'angular-route.js'
            include 'angular-route.min.js'
        }
        'angular-animate'('1.5.x', into: 'angular') {
            include 'angular-animate.js'
            include 'angular-animate.min.js'
        }               

    }

}

assets {
  minifyJs = true
  minifyCss = true
}
```

Please see the following blog for details of architecture of sample Spring Boot Project with angular.:

https://ghariaonline.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/spring-boot-with-angular-using-gradle/

Comment: Looks interesting. Will take a look at this soon.