# Gradle non-managed remote dependency

Tags: jar, gradle, dependency-management

I have a `jar` dependency that resides on a remote server. How do I resolve that in Gradle? There doesn't seem to be a way to define a repository for remote files, only local files, and I'm something like this doesn't seem to work either:

```
compile("group:name:version") {
  artifact {
    url = "http://server/dep.jar"
  }
}
```

The docs seems to hint that something like this should be possible, but so far I'm unable to find an example anywhere.

> Support for non-managed dependencies: If your dependencies are simply files in version control or a shared drive, Gradle provides powerful functionality to support this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can define a *custom maven repository* as in this question + answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754898/is-it-possible-to-include-angularjs-to-a-project-with-gradle and resolve the artifact that way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, according to [gradle documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories) a remote share is currently not supported.
However, this can be worked-around easily by doing the following:

1. Copy that will copy the remote jars locally. A possible location for such code can be the repositories configuration to ensure that the files will be copied before the dependencies will get resolved.
2. Define a local repository pointing to the local location of jars.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to download? Presumably after that, I can just use a `flatDir` repo?