# How to setup this gradle dependency?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, crosswalk-runtime

In a crosswalk project I have the following dependency:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:10.39.235.15'
}
```

This works, however I need version 13 which not available through the method above. I need to include:

https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/canary/13.41.313.0/crosswalk-13.41.313.0.aar

How would I set this up without downloading it locally first?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020073/gradle-non-managed-remote-dependency) post, it's not supported so you have 2 options:

1. Write a gradle task that downloads it to a local lib directory
2. Manually add it to a maven repo that you have control of, and then depend on it as you would any other maven dependency.

Comment: What is the gradle task to download it locally?

Comment: You'd have to write that yourself, or use a plugin that someone else has made, such as https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task