# How to integrate angular 4 with Spring MVC using gradle?

Tags: spring, angular, gradle

I found related SO answers for angularjs and angular 2
[Is it possible to include AngularJs to a project with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754898/is-it-possible-to-include-angularjs-to-a-project-with-gradle)

I tried using gradle node plugin to build the angular web app
https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md#executing-npm-tasks

Standalone I am able to execute both the spring MVC and the angular web app, but could not figure out how to build them and deploy it onto the same tomcat container.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new app using JHipster then take a look at the code to see how it's done. Angular, Spring Boot, and Gradle will be there. You can find the JHipster doc here: https://jhipster.github.io/